# Write a list into Excel

Tags: python, excel, list, file, tagging

I have a sentence 'And now for something completely different'. I want to tokenize it, tag it and store it into a excel file for further processing. 
`<pre>sent = "And now for something completely different"
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
tags = nltk.pos_tag()
print tags</pre>`

The result of above is the words with their tag in a nested list format.

> [('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
>   ('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]

I want to store this result list into a excel file, with words in one column and tags to the other.
I tried the following code to achieve the above.

```
fd = open("output.txt",'w')
i=0
for words in tags:
    for word in words:
        i+=1
        fd.write(word)
        if i==1:
            fd.write('\t')
        fd.write('\n')
    i=0
```

The above code will perfectly write the words and tag into the output file. If I use shutil method to copy from the text file to excel format, it will execute perfectly. The problem comes when I try to read the converted. I get the following error.

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or currupt file: Expected BOF record; founf 'And\tCC\n'

Can anyone tell me how do I write the tagged list to the output file such that I the above error can be resolved?

Comment: How do you use shutil to copy from text to excel format? Are you aware that excel format is not just file extension (.xlsx). It means that content of file should be orginized in special way, so that Excel application know how to read it. Generally you could either use [xlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) module, or you can write file in  [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format, and then import it in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel files (xlsx) are not just simple flat files, so trying to copy a text file to xlsx will not work.  You could save the file as csv and open it in Excel.  I think pandas is really useful for parsing and writing data files (obviously it is also useful for processing data).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(tags)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about pandas but will try what you have suggested and let you know the results.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested. I works. Thank you very much. Will this work if I have more than one sentence?

Comment: Yeah.  You can also output to different sheets, start on a different cell, or output with headers / index.  Use pd.ExcelWriter if you want to write multiple tables to different locations at once.

Answer (score 1):

Instead writing to excel format. You already writing your file into a tab-separated-value. Excel knows how to read that. I suggest you save your file with '.tsv' extension and open it in excel.

Comment: I tried saving the file in .ts format and I'm still getting the same error. Thank you for the suggestion.